ERROR: from pycaret.classification import * in google colab
I am trying to use pycaret in google colab.
Installed:
pip install pycaret[mlops]

But when I try to import
from pycaret.classification import *

I am getting this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4749d8b2394f> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 import seaborn as sns
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 6 from pycaret.classification import *
      7 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      8 import gradio as gr

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pycaret/internal/memory.py in <module>
     23 
     24 from joblib.hashing import Hasher, Pickler
---> 25 from joblib.memory import (
     26     MemorizedFunc,
     27     MemorizedResult,

ImportError: cannot import name '_format_load_msg' from 'joblib.memory' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/joblib/memory.py)

Tried restarting the runtime session but to no avail.
